# Can I use Advance Parole (I-131 Travel Document) to transit through European airports?

Tags: visas, transit, paperwork, us-residents, iranian-citizens

I'm an Iranian citizen currently living in the US. My green card application is pending right now but I received my advance parole or I-131 travel document. I want to go to Turkey and come back to the US. I see that the cheapest tickets have stop on one of the EU airports, usually Amsterdam or Paris. Am I allowed to transit through these airports due to that I'm an Iranian citizen? I will be in one of the EU airports just for 2 or 3 hours and obviously I don't want to go outside of the transit area. Do I need to apply for transit visa?

Comment: As you may be aware, transit that requires a change of airport (whether by ground, for example from Charles de Gaulle to Orly, or by air, for example from Paris to Amsterdam) isn't covered by an airport transit visa.  For such an itinerary you would need a regular short-stay visa.

Comment: @phoog I'm aware of that, but the ticket I'm thinking to buy is from ATL to AMS and AMS to IST and again for returning is from IST to CDG and CDG to ATL. So, I don't change airport.

Comment: That is good to hear.  I think the comment should remain, however, for future readers who might be in a similar situation.  It's a fairly common mistake for people who can't use the airport transit visa (or exemption) to think that they can.

Comment: It's NOT only about changing airports, it's about whether this is on one ticket or on two ticket. If ATL->AMS is a different ticket than AMS-> IST the OP needs to collect bags enter the Shengen area do a fresh check in in AMS. Same airport is not enough to stay airside in the transit area, it needs to be a single ticket with the bags checked through

Comment: @Hilmar it’s a single ticket for both ways.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure this trip already happened, but for other Iranian citizens in a similar situation, see the Timatic output below for travel from USA to third-country via the Netherlands.

Note: An I-131 document is NOT listed here as a qualifier for TWOV.

[image: Iran Transfer]